# Bash. Запуск nano на удалённой машине

Tags: linux, bash, администрирование

Здравствуйте! Хочу выполнить запуск локального скрипта на удалённой машине. В скрипте будет запуск редактирования файла с помощью `nano`.
Выглядит это так:

```
ssh -t user@host 'bash -s ' test.sh
./test.sh nano /home/user/file
```

На выходе ошибка

> Error opening terminal: unknown.

Comment: программе nano нужно знать характеристики терминала. обычно для передачи этой информации процессам используется [переменная окружения TERM](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/The-TERM-variable.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно изменить значение переменной TERM .